# How I can Move Site-Packages from Virtualenv to my App folder in Django

Tags: django

I have some packages installed in my website, but i want to move 1 package from virtual env to Django app folder (Which i Created), I copied complete folder of package from virtual env to my App folder, but no changing showing, Please let me know the process, How i can do it.

Comment: what does "but no changing showing" mean?

Comment: I want to move from site-packages to my app folder...

Comment: I understand what you want, but you're not telling us what the problem is after you moved it. You just say "but no changing showing" which doesn't mean anything. Do you see an error? If nothing changes, then it worked, right? Nothing should change after you move it to an app folder inside your project, it should just work. What change are you expecting? And when you say "copied" you mean you now have 2 directories with the app?

Comment: The proper way to do it is to `pip uninstall <package>` then download the source code of the package and install that as an app inside your django project.

Comment: I installed OSCAR Package in my website, and now i move oscar folder (from env file)  to my app files, but it's showing page not found.

Comment: Could i do it without uninstall from my website...Because this package already install in ENV file

Comment: well yes, if you really want to, you can *move* the package inside *path_to_env/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages* to your project directory, next to your other apps.

Comment: if you see an error, you should tell us in more detail what the error is. Which page is not found, which url is causing it, where's the full error trace (in development you should see more than just page not found in your console) etc...